# Removing messages from MassTranssit

Tags: c#, masstransit

How is the best way to implement task management in MassTranssit.
when a message with CorrelationId has an error and than i want to remove from all queues the messages with this CorrelationId.
How I implement this?

Comment: RMQ has no "deletion" feature, except using the management plugin API. MassTransit also does not support "deleting" messages. I would carefully reconsider the chosen design, which requires such functionality. I design message-driven systems for many years and never needed to remove messages manually, other than emptying the error queue.

Comment: if i publish message and one service will wnat to stop the message from consuming, how i make other services to not consume message with this CorrelationId

Comment: That isn't how messaging works - it is decoupled by design for scalability and asynchronous processing. If you need to "cancel" you might rethink which events are being consumed, and build out some type of workflow using a saga.